# How to scroll a DIV to the top of the browser window based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page that has many divs, containing a number of form fields that the user needs to fill out.

Now within one of the divs, I have a radiogroup option that determines additional DIVs being made available to the user for input using jQuery `.show()`.

My question is, when the user selects the radiogroup option, the new DIV appears below this radiogroup option but what I would like, would be a means to scroll this new DIV to the top of the browser so that the user doesn’t miss it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's the `<body>` that get scrolled, you could do this:

```
var newdiv = $('#div_id');

$('body').animate({scrollTop: newdiv.position().top});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/V36WL/1/

Comment: @tonsils: You're welcome. If the element being scrolled to is nested in some other container, you may need to use `newdiv.offset().top` instead, which gets the top position relative to the entire document.